# absolutely positioned divs that don't move when page is scrolled

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I've done this in the past using a method similar to this:
http://javascriptkit.com/javatutors/static3.shtml

but I don't like the "flicker" effect as the page is scrolled and the div needs to move with the scrolling.  Lately I've seen a lot of site that have an element (a div or the like I presume) that don't move when the page is scrolled but it's seemless...they're just there and it's a beautiful thing.

Unfortunately I can't seem to recall where I've seen it lately to view the source and try to figure it out so I figured I'd turn here and see what all of you experts can provide as far as assistance / suggestions.

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting "position: fixed" to the element.

I think this does not work with some IE versions, you'll have to us JS for that.

Answer (score 3):

That site you linked to still mentions thing such as IE 4 on it, better no rely on it. It's outdated.

You can position an element to a fixed position with CSS, by doing `position: fixed;`.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at **[google reader](http://reader.google.com)**.

It has a **fixed header** and a **fixed side bar.**

Comment: You really can't just point someone to a web page and not give any explanation. Answers that standalone and stand the test of time are best for the entire community. Google Reader is now dead and your answer with it.